# Control flow of execution

Tags: c#, blazor

It is a small challenge to express my problem properly but hopefully you people will understand my description.

I have a Blazor component to ask the user a yes or no question.

In one of my functions I want to use it:

```
YesOrNoDialogHeader = "What do you want?";
YesOrNoDialogMessage = "Answer Yes or No";
YesOrNoDialogVisible = true;

if (myResult == DialogYesOrNoResult.Yes)
{
  //Do something
}
```

My component has Yes and No buttons and functions accordingly which set the `myResult` variable to yes or no.

My problem is that I loose control of the flow here and the execution continues without getting the response from the component. How can I retrieve the control and write the code to handle the user response?

... Edit:
Actually I do not have my own component here but I am using one from Syncfusion like this:

```
<SfDialog Width="500px" IsModal="true" @bind-Visible="@YesOrNoDialogVisible">
    <DialogTemplates>
        <Header>@YesOrNoDialogHeader </Header>
        <Content>@YesOrNoDialogMessage</Content>
    </DialogTemplates>
    <DialogButtons>
        <DialogButton Content="Yes" IsPrimary="true" OnClick="@DialogYesResponse" />
        <DialogButton Content="No" OnClick="@DialogNoResponse" />
    </DialogButtons>
</SfDialog>
```

Comment: All component will rung thought its whole life cycle. Please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: You could also use [SweetAlert2 for Blazor](https://github.com/Basaingeal/Razor.SweetAlert2) or at least take a look at their source code on how they do it.

Answer (score 0):

In your code this line `OnClick="@DialogYesResponse"` will be looking for a method signature that looks like this:

```
protected void DialogYesResponse(MouseEventArgs e)
{
..
..
}
```

automatically sending `MouseEventArgs` because that is the default callback signature.

If you want to send back something other than the `MouseEventArgs` on a button click your button `OnClick` callback can use an anonymous callback/function.

Here is a page that shows in a label if you clicked yes or no.

```
@page "/yesornopage"

<h3>YesOrNoPage</h3>

<button @onclick="@(() => { YesOrNoDialogVisible = !YesOrNoDialogVisible; })"
        class="btn btn-light">
    Show Dialog
</button>

<label>You clicked : @myResult</label>

<SfDialog Width="500px" IsModal="true" @bind-Visible="@YesOrNoDialogVisible">
    <DialogTemplates>
        <Header>@YesOrNoDialogHeader </Header>
        <Content>@YesOrNoDialogMessage</Content>
    </DialogTemplates>
    <DialogButtons>
        <DialogButton Content="Yes" IsPrimary="true" OnClick="@(()=> { OnYesOrNoButtonClick(true); })" />
        <DialogButton Content="No" OnClick="@(()=> { OnYesOrNoButtonClick(false); })" />
    </DialogButtons>
</SfDialog>

@code {
    enum DialogYesOrNoResult
    {
        Yes,
        No
    }

    string YesOrNoDialogHeader = "What do you want?";
    string YesOrNoDialogMessage = "Answer Yes or No";
    bool YesOrNoDialogVisible = false;
    DialogYesOrNoResult myResult = DialogYesOrNoResult.No;

    protected void OnYesOrNoButtonClick(bool result)
    {
        if (result == true)
            myResult = DialogYesOrNoResult.Yes;
        else
            myResult = DialogYesOrNoResult.No;

        YesOrNoDialogVisible = false;
    }

}
```

or you could send back something other than a bool like this example below:

```
<SfDialog Width="500px" IsModal="true" @bind-Visible="@YesOrNoDialogVisible">
    <DialogTemplates>
        <Header>@YesOrNoDialogHeader </Header>
        <Content>@YesOrNoDialogMessage</Content>
    </DialogTemplates>
    <DialogButtons>
        <DialogButton Content="Yes" IsPrimary="true" OnClick="@(()=> { OnYesOrNoButtonClick(DialogYesOrNoResult.Yes); })" />
        <DialogButton Content="No" OnClick="@(()=> { OnYesOrNoButtonClick(DialogYesOrNoResult.No); })" />
    </DialogButtons>
</SfDialog>

@code {
    protected enum DialogYesOrNoResult
    {
        Yes,
        No,
        None
    }

    string YesOrNoDialogHeader = "What do you want?";
    string YesOrNoDialogMessage = "Answer Yes or No";
    bool YesOrNoDialogVisible = false;
    DialogYesOrNoResult myResult = DialogYesOrNoResult.None;

    protected void OnYesOrNoButtonClick(DialogYesOrNoResult result)
    {
        myResult = result;

        YesOrNoDialogVisible = false;
    }

}
```